# Supervisor socket error issue

Tags: supervisord

```
$ supervisorctl reread
error: <class 'socket.error'>, [Errno 111] Connection refused: file: /usr/lib64/python2.6/socket.py line: 567
```

I'm trying to configure supervisor on my production system, but am hitting this error. The supervisor log file is empty.

When I just type `supervisorctl`, it complains:

```
http://localhost:9001 refused connection
```

Nothing is currently listening on port 9001, AFACT: `lsof | grep TCP` returns nothing.

Comment: see this : https://stackoverflow.com/a/66931708/5999939

Answer (score 194, accepted):

You have to start supervisord before you can use supervisorctl. In my case:

```
sudo supervisord -c /etc/supervisor/supervisord.conf
sudo supervisorctl -c /etc/supervisor/supervisord.conf
```

Comment: You shouldn't have to sudo supervisorctl, but I ran into permissions issues that caused me to give up on solving that problem

Comment: I have same issued as kelorek but above command did not work on me.

Comment: What returns when you hit enter?

Comment: http://192.168.111.100:9001 refused connection

Comment: You shouldn't have to specify the conf path. Both tools should be using the same default path. If they're not, then you may have a corrupted installation.

Comment: This didnt fix the issue but showed me the exact error which was actually a log file not being created for a supervisor config of Django.

Answer (score 43):

If you started supervisord with a custom path, like this:

```
sudo supervisord -c /mypath/supervisord.conf
```

Then you should also start supervisorctl with the same parameter, like this:

```
sudo supervisorctl -c /mypath/supervisord.conf
```

Answer (score 14):

You can get this issue if you start supervisor with a relative url for `-c` and then try run supervisorctl from a different directory.

For example:

```
supervisord -c supervisord.conf
supervisorctl start someapp ## works 
cd somedirectory
supervisorctl restart someapp ## http://localhost:9001 refused connection
```

Solution would be to always use the absolute path. e.g.:

**Good:**

```
supervisord -c /etc/supervisor/supervisord.conf
```

**Bad:**

```
supervisord -c supervisord.conf
```

Answer (score 6):

please do the following :

`sudo service supervisor start`

post which everything is normal as b4 - there is a problem with 1b version

`sudo supervisorctl reload`

Answer (score 5):

This issue also occurs when an old vesion of `supervisord.conf` file is used. 
Newer version of supervisor uses different configuration file.
The above solutions don't work.
In this case you just have to regenerate the configuration file with

```
echo_supervisord_conf > /etc/supervisord.conf
```

Hope it helps someoone.

Answer (score 2):

### In Ubuntu 18.04 with distribution's package

You probably did the same mistake as me an created the config file `/etc/supervisord.conf` while my service manager (**systemd**) was using the config file `/etc/supervisor/supervisord.conf`

`sudo rm /etc/supervisord.conf`

**Or**

`sudo mv /etc/supervisord.conf /etc/supervisor/supervisord.conf`

if you want to keep it

Now you can run `sudo supervisorctl`

---

#### Why?

when you run `supervisorctl` it first searches for the config file located at `/etc/supervisord.conf`, if it's not present, it will search for the package's default file `/etc/supervisor/supervisord.conf` this is the one **systemd** actually runs.

**Systemd** always use the file `/etc/supervisor/supervisord.conf` regardless of the other file's existence.

You can check which file is using **systemd** by running `sudo systemctl status supervisor`

[image]
You can see in the last line the command where the config file is hardcoded

Answer (score -1):

both `supervisord` and `supervisorctl` use `-c` with absolute config file path, make sure both commands startup with same config.