# Supervisor no such file socket.py

Tags: laravel, ubuntu, homestead, supervisord

I am trying to setup a queue listener for laravel and cannot seem to get supervisor working correctly.  I get the following error when I run `supervisorctl reload`:

`error: <class 'socket.error'>, [Errno 2] No such file or directory: file: /usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py line: 228`

The file DOES exist. If try to run `sudo supervisorctl` I get this 
`unix:///var/run/supervisor.sock no such file`.

I've tried reinstall supervisor and that did not work either. Not sure what to do here.

I'm running Laravel Homestead (Ubuntu 16.04).

Result of `service supervisor status`:
`vagrant@homestead:~/Code$ sudo service supervisor status
● supervisor.service - Supervisor process control system for UNIX
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/supervisor.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: activating (auto-restart) (Result: exit-code) since Thu 2016-12-22 11:06:21 EST; 41s ago
     Docs: http://supervisord.org
  Process: 23154 ExecStop=/usr/bin/supervisorctl $OPTIONS shutdown (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 23149 ExecStart=/usr/bin/supervisord -n -c /etc/supervisor/supervisord.conf (code=exited, status=2)
 Main PID: 23149 (code=exited, status=2)`

Comment: It sounds like supervisor is installed but not running. Try `service supervisor --status` and let us know what that says. (it might be "services", not "service" -- I haven't memorized all of my linux invocations)

Comment: I've added the result of `service supervisor status` to my question

Comment: First start supervisor with `sudo service supervisor start` & next  `sudo supervisorctl`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up just removing supervisor entirely, reinstalling and rewriting my config files. I must have just done something wrong in the process and wasn't able to catch it.

Comment: If one goes this way, make sure you backup your configs:``cp -r /etc/supervisor/conf.d/ ~/supervisor/``

Answer (score 46):

You should run `sudo service supervisor start` when you are in the supervisor dir.

Worked for me.

Comment: This is also relevant to centos: `sudo systemctl start supervisord` worked for me

Comment: which one is the supervisor dir?

Answer (score 28):

> **2020 UPDATE**
>
> Try running `sudo service supervisor start` in your terminal before using the below solution. I found out that the issue sometimes occurs when `supervisor` is not running, nothing complicated.

I am using `Ubuntu 18.04`. I had the same problem and re-installing supervisor did not solve my problem.

I ended up completely removing the conf.d directory and recreating it with new configs. **Make sure you back up your configurations before trying this**:

1. `sudo rm -rf /etc/supervisor/conf.d/`
2. `sudo mkdir /etc/supervisor/conf.d`
3. `sudo nano /etc/supervisor/conf.d/my-file.conf`
4. Copy+Paste your configuration into your new file.

`sudo supervisorctl reread` started working again.

Answer (score 12):

### In Ubuntu 18.04 with distribution's package

You probably did the same mistake as me an created the config file `/etc/supervisord.conf` while my service manager (**systemd**) was using the config file `/etc/supervisor/supervisord.conf`

### Solutions

- Remove the config file created

  ```
  sudo rm /etc/supervisord.conf
  ```
- Move it to the ***correct*** location

  ```
  sudo mv /etc/supervisord.conf /etc/supervisor/supervisord.conf
  ```

Now you can run `sudo supervisorctl`

---

### Why?

when you run `supervisorctl` it first searches for the config file located at `/etc/supervisord.conf`, if it's not present, it will search for the package's default file `/etc/supervisor/supervisord.conf` this is the one **systemd** actually runs.

**Systemd** always use the file `/etc/supervisor/supervisord.conf` regardless of the other file's existence.

You can check which file is using **systemd** by running `sudo systemctl status supervisor`

[image]
You can see in the last line the command where the config file is hardcoded

Comment: This is the best solution. I faced the issue when reinstall supervisor without remove. 

I just remove the file <code>/etc/supervisord.conf</code> then the issue is resolved
Thank you so much for the solution.

Answer (score 5):

I had a very similar problem (Ubuntu 18.04) and searched similar threads to no avail so answering here with some more comprehensive answers.

Lack of a sock file or socket error is only an indicator that supervisor is not running.  If a simple restart doesn't work its either 1. not installed, or 2. failing to start.   In my case nothing was being logged to the supervisor.log file for me to know why it was failing until I ran the following command (-n to run in foreground) only to find out that there was a leftover configuration file for a project that had been deleted that I missed.

```
/usr/bin/supervisord -n -c /etc/supervisor/supervisord.conf
```

Once I deleted the bad/leftover file in the conf.d folder and started it back up with `sudo service supervisor start` everything worked.

Here are some comprehensive steps you can take.

1. Is supervisor installed?  `dpkg -l | grep supervisor` If not reinstall `sudo apt install supervisor`
2. Are all instances of supervisor stopped? `systemctl stop supervisor` Lingering supervisor processes can be found `ps aux | grep supervisor` then `kill -9 PID`.
3. Is supervisor.conf in the right location `/etc/supervisor/supervisor.conf` and there are no syntax errors?  Reinstall from package would correct this.
4. Move your specific files in conf.d/ temporarily out of the folder to try and start with no additional config files.  If it starts right up `sudo service supervisor start` the likelihood of an error in your project .conf file exists.
5. Check status with `sudo service supervisor status`.
6. Move your .conf files one by one back into conf.d/ and restart `sudo service supervisor restart`.  Be sure to check with `sudo service supervisor status` between. If it fails you know which .conf file has an issue and can ask for specific help.
7. check everything is running with `supervisorctl status` and if not start with `supervisorctl start all`.

Answer (score 5):

None of about answers helped me.
the problem was i didn't follow [supervisor documentation](http://supervisord.org/installing.html).
and a step i didn't do was run `echo_supervisord_conf` command that makes the configuration file.

****Steps i did for**** **Ubuntu 18.04:**

**Installing supervisor (without pip):**

1. `sudo apt-get install supervisor`
2. `echo_supervisord_conf > /etc/supervisord.conf` (with root access: first run `sudo -i` then `echo_supervisord_conf > /etc/supervisord.conf`)
3. change python dependency to python2

> (`Depends: python-pkg-resources, init-system-helpers (>= 1.18~), python-meld3, python:any (<< 2.8), python:any (>= 2.7.5-5~)`

in these files: `/usr/bin/supervisord` | `/usr/bin/supervisorctl` | `/usr/bin/echo_supervisord_conf`.
Just change the first line from `#!/usr/bin/python` to `#!/usr/bin/python2`

4. run `supervisord`
5. Finish

hope help !

Answer (score 3):

Facing the `python file not found an error, code=exited, status=2` once I try with the official document but still same.
I have tried so many solutions for my laravel application.

But at last, I have tried with my solution.

Here is an example for the code :

```
[program:dev-worker]
process_name=%(program_name)s_%(process_num)02d
command=php /var/www/html/example.com/artisan queue:work --sleep=3 --tries=3
autostart=true
autorestart=true
user=ubuntu
numprocs=8
redirect_stderr=true
stdout_logfile=/var/www/html/example.com/storage/logs/laravel.log
stopwaitsecs=3600
```

Ref: https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/queues#supervisor-configuration

Answer (score 3):

On Centos 7 I use the following...

```
supervisord -c /path/to/supervisord.conf
```

followed by...

```
supervisorctl -c /path/to/supervisord.conf
```

This gets rid of the ".sock file not found" error. Now you have to kill old processes using...

```
ps aux|grep gunicorn
```

Kill the offending processes using...

```
kill <pid>
```

Then again...

```
supervisorctl -c /path/to/supervisord.conf
```

Supervisor should now be running properly if your config is good.

Answer (score 2):

You can try by removing all of the related folder of supervisor & uninstall supervisor completely.

```
sudo rm -rf /var/log/supervisor/supervisord.log 
sudo rm -rf /etc/supervisor/conf.d/
```

After doing this, reinstall supervisor by

```
sudo apt install supervisor
```

Now, you can run correctly. Check with

```
sudo systemctl status supervisor
```

Answer (score 2):

If by running `sudo service supervisor status` you get the following:

`ExecStart=/usr/bin/supervisord -n -c /etc/supervisor/supervisord.conf (code=exited, status=2)`

Try running `/usr/bin/supervisord`, it will give you clear message to tell you where the error is.

Answer (score 1):

Check the *supervisord.conf* file.

Look for the following:

```
[unix_http_server]
file=/path/to/supervisor.sock/file   ; (the path to the socket file)   
chmod=0700                           ; sockef file mode(default 0700)
```

Go to the path mentioned above and check if the file is present.
If it is present then try re-installing supervisor.

If not then search for *supervisor.sock* file either using the command line or file explorer GUI.

Copy the file found in the above step to the location specified in the [unix_http_server] by using the cp command or GUI.

For me, the *supervisor.sock* was present in the /run folder.

Comment: My `supervisor.sock` file was missing completely. reinstalling supervisor fixed it for me.

Answer (score 0):

you can try

```
sudo touch /var/run/supervisor.sock
sudo chmod 777 /var/run/supervisor.sock
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue because we were using supervisorctl to manage gunicorn. The root of my problem had nothing to do with supervisor (it was handling other processes just fine) or the python sock.py file (file was there, permissions were correct), but rather the gunicorn config file `/etc/supervisor/conf.d/gunicorn.conf`. This configuration file was managed by a source-controlled template with environment variables and when we updated the template on the server, the template variables were never replaced with the actual data. So for example something in the gunicorn.conf file read `user={{ user }}` instead of `user=gunicorn`. When supervisor tried to parse this config when running `supervisorctl start gunicorn` it would crash with this socket error. Repairing the gunicorn.conf file resolved the supervisor issue.

Answer (score 0):

> Source of answer : http://supervisord.org/installing.html

1. Run command : `echo_supervisord_conf`
2. Once you see the file echoed to your terminal, reinvoke the command as `echo_supervisord_conf > /etc/supervisord.conf`. This won’t work if you do not have root access.
3. If you don’t have root access, or you’d rather not put the `supervisord.conf` file in `/etc/supervisord.conf`, you can place it in the current directory (`echo_supervisord_conf > supervisord.conf`) and start supervisord with the `-c` flag in order to specify the configuration file location.

The error should've been resolved by now.

Answer (score 0):

I did the following to solve the issue on CentOS Linux 7

```
sudo systemctl status supervisord.service
```

With the above command, I realise that the program was in active

```
sudo systemctl start supervisord.service
```

Now I use the command above to start the service and everything works well now

Answer (score 0):

My problem turned out to be an invalid directory specified in a conf.d file (in my case, the Horizon package in the Laravel framework).

```
[program:horizon]
process_name=%(program_name)s
command=php /var/www/projects/myInvalidPath/artisan horizon
autostart=true
autorestart=true
redirect_stderr=true
stdout_logfile=/var/www/projects/myInvalidPath/storage/logs/horizon.log
stopwaitsecs=3600
```

This invalid config would throw `error: <class 'FileNotFoundError'>, [Errno 2] No such file or directory: file: /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/supervisor/xmlrpc.py line: 560`

Interestingly, a far more useful error is reported if the logfile is invalid, which led me to the discovery:

`ERROR: CANT_REREAD: The directory named as part of the path /var/www/projects/myInvalidPath/storage/logs/horizon.log does not exist in section 'program:horizon' (file: '/etc/supervisor/conf.d/horizon.conf')`